# Postfix LDAP aliases - user unknown

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot, ndr

I have server POSTFIX + DOVECOT with LDAP (ActiveDirectory) authorization.

**/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf**

```
query_filter = (&(objectClass=person)(mail=%s))
result_filter = %s
result_attribute = mail
```

**/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_alias_maps.cf**

```
query_filter = (&(objectClass=person)(othermailbox=%s))
result_attribute = othermailbox
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext**

```
pass_filter = (&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=%n))
user_filter = (&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=%n))
```

The email specified in the attribute "mail" works (users can send and receive messages). I specify an alias in the attribute "othermailbox" (for example - s15@domain.com).

```
    # postmap -q s15@domain.com ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_virtual_alias_maps.cf
    s15@domain.com
```

When I send an email to this address (s15@domain.com) then get "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"

> The mail system s15@domain.com: user unknown

What am I doing wrong ? I will be grateful for comments.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect **the `result_attribute` in your `ldap_virtual_alias_maps.cf` is not what you meant** to configure.
A [virtual_alias_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) result that just the returns the lookup key by itself is not very useful (that feature is meant to alias one address to *other* addresses).

Usually, it would **look up** by *the additional address* (your field `othermailbox`), but it would still **return** the *primary address* (your field `mail`). You may want something like this.

```
# lookup by othermailbox
query_filter = (&(objectClass=person)(othermailbox=%s))
# but return primary address
result_attribute = mail
```

If you tell Postfix that `s15@example.com` is an alias for `s15@example.com`.. that does not tell Postfix where the mail should go. Because the (unchanged) destination `s15@example.com` is still not a known user.

Comment: Brilliant! That helped.
Thanks for the help.